# SonarQube MSBuild Runner defaults to h2 Database

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am using Win Server 2012, Developer Command Prompt for VS2013, SonarQube v5.1.2, SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 1.1.

I have my Sonar instance running off this same server, but connected to an Oracle database. Using the default sonar runner, i can analyze projects properly and see them appear in the dashboard using this method. That cannot be said for using the recommended MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe approach.

I have tried with the csharp and vbnet examples, as well as our actual code. Oddly, i want to say each of these have worked at least once, but fail to do so now. Today, I tried using the vbnet example project for the first time and discovered and it worked as intended when using the MSBuild runner. I deleted the project from the dashboard, and ran it again. At this point i do not remember it it worked or not, but the third time for sure it stopped working and began producing the error below (wherein it tries to connect to the default h2 database instead of the oracle one that SonarQube is connected to).

I tried deleting the examples folder, extracting it again, giving it a slightly different name, and running the Sonar on it giving THOSE a different name/key/version, but now it is consistently giving me the db error.

Any idea what could be going on here, and why it would go from working to not, without me making any changes to the runner, msbuild, or the code?

Running the begin step:

```
c:\sonar-examples-master\projects\languages\vbnet>msbuild.sonarqube.runner.exe b
egin /v:vbnet1 /k:vbnet1 /n:vbnet1
SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 1.1
Default properties file was found at c:\sonarqube\bin\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Loading analysis properties from c:\sonarqube\bin\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Pre-processing started.
Preparing working directories...
Checking for updates...
MSBuild SonarQube Runner Pre-processor 1.0.2.0
17:40:49.625  Loading analysis properties from c:\sonarqube\bin\SonarQube.Analys
is.xml
17:40:49.656  Updating build integration targets...
17:40:49.656  Fetching analysis configuration settings...
17:40:50.813  Generating rulesets...
Pre-processing succeeded.
```

MSBuild ran, but nothing worthwhile to post from it..

Running the end step:

```
c:\sonar-examples-master\projects\languages\vbnet>msbuild.sonarqube.runner.exe e
nd
SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 1.1
Default properties file was found at c:\sonarqube\bin\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Loading analysis properties from c:\sonarqube\bin\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Post-processing started.
MSBuild SonarQube Runner Post-processor 1.0.2.0
WARNING: File is not under the project directory and cannot currently be analyse
d by SonarQube. File: C:\Users\ts3conusr\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Versio
n=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.vb, project: c:\sonar-examples-master\projects\languag
es\vbnet\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.vbproj
The SONAR_RUNNER_HOME environment variable is not required and will be ignored.
SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS is not configured. Setting it to the default value of -Xmx1024
m
Calling the sonar-runner...
c:\sonar-examples-master\projects\languages\vbnet\.sonarqube\bin\sonar-runner\bi
n\..
SonarQube Runner 2.4
Java 1.7.0_79 Oracle Corporation (32-bit)
Windows Server 2008 R2 6.1 x86
SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS=-Xmx1024m
INFO: Error stacktraces are turned on.
INFO: Runner configuration file: c:\sonar-examples-master\projects\languages\vbn
et\.sonarqube\bin\sonar-runner\bin\..\conf\sonar-runner.properties
INFO: Project configuration file: c:\sonar-examples-master\projects\languages\vb
net\.sonarqube\out\sonar-project.properties
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
INFO: Work directory: c:\sonar-examples-master\projects\languages\vbnet\.sonarqu
be\out\.sonar
INFO: SonarQube Server 5.1.2
17:41:04.563 INFO  - Load global repositories
17:41:04.751 INFO  - Load global repositories (done) | time=188ms
17:41:04.751 INFO  - Server id: 20160120154951
17:41:04.751 INFO  - User cache: C:\Users\ts3conusr\.sonar\cache
17:41:04.766 INFO  - Install plugins
17:41:04.860 INFO  - Install JDBC driver
17:41:04.860 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/sonar
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 1.047s
Final Memory: 3M/15M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
```

Of note: I feel that it is worth mentioning that the vbnet report didn't actually have any content in it, but did at least properly get generated in the Sonar dashboard. I have tried running the commands against both that and the csharp example with now neither of them being added to the dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i upgraded to the latest SonarQube version (5.3) and upgraded a few of the extensions while i was at it and preliminary testing is showing positive results. Ill try it a few more times but im closing the question for now. Thank you all that helped!

Answer (score 0):

In the MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner install folder, there is a `SonarQube.Analysis.xml`. Do you have the correct server details on the below line in there?

```
<Property Name="sonar.host.url">http://{host}:{port}/{optionalPath}</Property>
```

This property value should point to your Sonar server.

Comment: It is the default address and port (pretty sure its localhost:9000) and i could also confirm that i could navigate to it from the server itself. Plus earlier today when i had it working and then not working with the vbnet example, i made no changes to SonarQube.Analysis.xml between it working and it not.

Answer (score 0):

Couple other things to try. Do you see tables being populated with analysis data in your oracle database? When was the last time it got any record?

Also, are you seeing below warning on your SonarQube application pages (say default dashboard)? If yes, then oracle configuration is not being picked up.

[image]